# Compiling X11 programs under ubuntu 22.04

Tags: xorg, compiling, 22.04

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 "Jammy Jellyfish", I can't seem to be able to compile programs that use X11. Is there something I need to install? The X11 include files seem to be missing (or they moved?).

Comment: Did you install the x11proto-dev package?

Comment: ... you can search what package provides a particular header file using [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/)

Comment: Okay, installed x11proto-dev, but still doesn't compile, maybe more needed? Using packages listing as suggested shows a whole bunch of X11 packages. I assume that I don't need to install them all, how to tell which ones I need?

Comment: Got it. apt-get install libx11-dev did it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install libx11-dev
```

Comment: Thanks, karel -- see my last comment above.