# ubuntu 22.04 jammy localectl VC Keymap & X11 Model

Tags: 22.04

settings I have used previously with ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 no longer work for 22.04 when setting locale.

settings are:-
localectl set-keymap gb ;
localectl --no-convert set-x11-keymap gb

by following [Compiling X11 programs under ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1411826/compiling-x11-programs-under-ubuntu-22-04), I installed 'libx11-dev' which solved my requirement to configure the 'X11 Layout', but I still can't configure the 'VC Keymap'

I've tried various solutions from the top dozen internet searches without luck.

these worked 'out the bag' with previous releases, how is 'VC Keymap' defined now with Ubuntu 22.04 ?

Answer (score 0):

`VC` is virtual console; I think you can use the one of the below to change keyboard layout:

```
$ sudo loadkeys uk
$ sudo loadkeys -C /dev/console uk
```

Comment: using either of those commands with 22.04 responds with:-
"/usr/bin/ckbcomp: Can not find file "symbols/uk" in any known directory
"